# Encapsulate objects in Java?

Tags: java, encapsulation

`private` in `Java` provides class level encapsulation. Is it possible to encapsulate an object instead? Or is this futile to do so?

For instance if we define a class as,

```
 public class Person {

      private String ssn;

      private ArrayList<Person> friends = new ArrayList<Person>();

      public void addFriend (Person stranger) {

           friends.add(stranger);

           // but here I have access to her ssn
           System.out.println(stranger.ssn);
      }
}
```

How would I shield access to `ssn` of `stranger` in the method `addFriend()` above when I require that the `stranger`'s object be passed to it as parameter?

Comment: You realize you're in the `Person` class right? You also have access to `stranger.ID`; `stranger` is a `Person`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think he does, and it's his question. Well, if it is : no, there is no way to hide a field of a class to other instances of the same class

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, like Dici has pointed out.

Comment: Then no. There is no such thing as a instance level access modifier. As I said in my first comment, you could have done `friends.add(stranger.ID);` so you haven't hidden anything from `Person`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have an "instance" private access modifier, ie. where you can restrict access only to `this` instance's fields/methods.

And you probably don't need one. You're in your `Person` class. You're the developer. What do you need to hide from yourself?

Comment: Are there languages who do?

Comment: @Alex [Scala for example.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_access_modifiers.htm)

Answer (score 3):

`private` means you have access to that member from that *class*, not just that *instance*.

You can only access `ssn` from inside `Person`, not from any other type. You can't circumvent this to restrict this to just that instance.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of encapsulation is not the same as the idea of data security.

Encapsulation is used to improve *programs*. It improves the ability of software to trust a class's contract and get the expected results without bugs, and it improves the ability to abstract implementation, allowing you to think in small units and not have side effects caused by unexpected usages.

For this reason, it is implemented at the *class* level. If you are a programmer, you are usually supposed to be able to trust yourself or your team members. There are several levels of trust here, but again, we're talking about trusting them to respect the class's contract.

Data security should be handled on a different level altogether. For example, by encrypting a sensitive field only with a secure key that is not stored anywhere except on the authorized person's computer, so that only that person can access it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mechanism for this built into the language. You can do it yourself, though, by adding an interface with methods that should be accessible to everyone, while keeping the inaccessible members to the type, like this:

```
public interface Person {
    int getID();
}

public class PersonWithSsn implements Person {
      private int ID;
      private String ssn;

      private ArrayList<Integer> friends = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      public int getID() {
           return ID;
      }
      public void addFriend (Person stranger) {
           friends.add(stranger.getID());
           // You no longer have access to ssn here
           //System.out.println(stranger.ssn);
      }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit pointless doing this. If the `Stranger` is a `PersonWithSsn` all you have to do is cast and then access `ssn` as normal.

Comment: @pbabcdefp By the same logic any other way of guarding an SSN from access would be futile because reflection APIs exist. Of course in Java you can get to things you're not supposed to see. However, that's not the point of this exercise. What happens to the cast when somebody passes a different implementation of `Person` is an entirely different story.

Comment: I gotta agree that this is a pretty nast hack. Yeah almost anything is possible via reflection, but casting is not reflection; this code is still "misusable"

Answer (score 1):

You could get past this by encapsulating your definitions separately, then passing the correct definition to the method:

```
class Person {
    private HiddenDefinitions hiddenDef;
    private PublicDefinitions publicDef;

    public void addFriend(PublicDefinitions def) {

    }
}

class PublicDefinitions {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }
}

class HiddenDefinitions {
    private String ssn;

    private String getSSN() {
            return ssn;
    }

    public void setSSN(String ssn) {
            this.ssn = ssn;
    }
}
```

This will ensure you only pass public information when needed. Although it does require extra classes, it prevents breakage possible by other examples